# how to understand the capacity in binary symetric channel (BSC)

Tags: noise, bandwidth, capacity, bit-error

According to the wiki about the [BSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel) (binary symetric channel), 
given the bit flip rate p, 
the capacity is derived as : 
H(p) = -p*log2(p) – (1-p)log2(1-p)
C = 1 - H(p).

the error probability p should be with [0, 0.5].
I am little bit confused about this condition.

For example, when p =0.2, H(0.2) = 0.7219280948873623, and the capacity is:0.2780719051126377. 
However, when p=0.9, H(0.9)=0.468996, and the capacity is :0.531004. 
Why the larger bit error probability results in a larger capacity?
And I can not understand why and how to **swap the output (interpret 1 when it sees 0, and vice versa)** just as the [BSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel) says.

Actually, the ber, H(p) and  capacity is the following relationship:

```
p=0.100000, h:0.468996, c:0.531004
p=0.200000, h:0.721928, c:0.278072
p=0.300000, h:0.881291, c:0.118709
p=0.400000, h:0.970951, c:0.029049
p=0.500000, h:1.000000, c:0.000000
p=0.600000, h:0.970951, c:0.029049
p=0.700000, h:0.881291, c:0.118709
p=0.800000, h:0.721928, c:0.278072
p=0.900000, h:0.468996, c:0.531004
```

Any one could help me understand it?
Any hints would be appreciate!

Comment: it seems the channel entropy increases with noise bandwidth as BER reduces is expected. But the errors should be symmetrical. I am concerned with your excessive digits beyond sigfigs in grasping the concepts.

Comment: If the two symbols have probability of 99% and 1%, how much information can be transmitted, compared to 50% and 50%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the extreme. If your bit error rate is 1, then you know with certainty that the bit was flipped. If you receive a 1, the value sent was 0. So, flip the bit. This is why p=1 is the same as p=0.

Similarly, any time it's more than 50% likely that the received bit has flipped, you get better ber by just flipping the bit. Does that make more sense now?